# How print statement create a local variables

Tags: python, python-internals

Question are at the end of this post.

**First snippet:** empty local variable dictionary.

```
def outer():
    x = 1
    def inner():
        print "Local variables: %s" % locals()
    return inner()
print outer()
```

Output:
    Local variables: {}

**Second snippet:** print inside inner() function and creating local variable entry.

```
def outer():
    x = 1
    def inner():
        print x
        print "Local variables: %s" % locals()
    return inner()
print outer()
```

Output:

```
1
Local variables: {'x': 1}
```

**Third Snippet**: del x from inside the inner function:

```
def outer():
    x = 1
    def inner():
        print x
        print "Local variables: %s" % locals()
        del x
    return inner()
print outer()
```

Output:

```
>>> outer()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in outer
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in inner
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

Questions :

1. In Second Snippet, how print statement create local variable.
2. If it creates local variable inside inner function why I am not able to delete it.

Could someone please help me understanding this.

Comment: A quick search revealed a duplicate question, but the answers for it aren't very good. Some of the information in the answers is outright wrong. I'm not voting to close.

Comment: From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals): "Free variables are returned by [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) when it is called in function blocks, but not in class blocks."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Short Description of Python Scoping Rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

Comment: thank you @martijn, got lots of info from that link too.

Comment: Somewhere there's a great article by… I think Raymond Hettinger?… that explains how Python closures work in detail. Unfortunately, I can't remember where. And there are a lot of really bad articles that turn up in a Google search.

Comment: Thank you @abarnet if you found out any please comment it, that will be very helpful for myself and many others who are new to the language.

Comment: @abarnert This [one](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/09/18/python-internals-symbol-tables-part-1/) by Eli Bendersky perhaps.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: That's not the one I was looking for. But that's a pretty impressive series, which covers closures along with all kinds of other things, and does so in a systematic way rather than jumping right in to the bytecode and how it uses values from the function and code objects. So it might be even more useful than the one I can't find. +1, and I'll copy your link to my answer for future searchers who don't like to read comments.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Python, unless you specify otherwise (with a `global` statement, or a `nonlocal` statement in 3.0+), a variable is in `locals` if you modify it (assign to it, `del` it, etc.) anywhere in the function.*

In the first snippet, you never modify `x`, or even access it, so it's not local. In fact, it doesn't even exist. That's easy.

The second version is the tricky one. `x` is not local to `inner`, because you don't modify it in `inner`. So, Python goes looking for it, moving outward scope by scope, until it finds it a scope that has that variable. And it finds it as a local variable in `outer`. Which means it's a *closure variable* or *free variable* in `inner`. Since the [`locals`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) function includes closure variables as well as local variables, you see it.

The third version, by doing `del x`, makes `x` local to `inner`.** So, it appears in `locals`. However, you try to `print` it without having ever assigned anything to it, so there is no value yet. So you get an `UnboundLocalError`.

Generally, once you understand the basic idea Python is trying to accomplish here, it's usually obvious what kind of variable you have. But if it's ever unclear, the detailed rules  are defined in [Naming and Binding](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding).

---

If you want to understand how closures work under the covers, you can start by inspecting the function objects. Try this:

```
def outer():
    x = 1
    def inner():
        print x
        print "Local variables: %s" % locals()
    return inner
inner = outer()
print inner.func_closure
print inner.func_code.co_freevars
print outer.func_code.co_cellvars
```

The [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module docs list all of the important members of `function`, `code`, and other "under the covers" objects.

Using the [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module to look at the bytecode for `outer` and `inner` may also be helpful.*** For example, if you run [this code](http://pastebin.com/RgVQXe0v), you'll see a `LOAD_FAST` for the local, `LOAD_DEREF` for the cell, and `LOAD_GLOBAL` for the global.

But if you really want to understand how all of this really works, the series of articles on [symbol tables](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/09/18/python-internals-symbol-tables-part-1/) at Eli Bendersky's "Python internals" blog covers just about everything very nicely. (Thanks to Ashwini Chaudhary for locating it and pointing it out in a comment.)

---

* This is checked at compile time, not execution time, so trying to confuse it with, e.g., `exec` can successfully confuse both Python and yourself.

** Note that `del` counts as both an modification and an access. This can be surprising, but you can see that `def foo(): del x` will raise an `UnboundLocalError` because the `del` makes `x` local, and the very same `del` fails to find a value.

*** … assuming you're using a Python implementation that uses CPython-style bytecode, like CPython itself (of course) or PyPy.

Comment: in the third snippet even i didn't print also got the same error when i tried to del.

Comment: @yopy: In that case, you're trying to delete a variable before you've created it, which is a different error, but not _that_ different. And you can see that without any of this fancy stuff: `def foo(): del x`.

Comment: @Cilyan: `inner` is a closure. The fact that he calls the closure immediately and returns its value, instead of returning the closure itself, doesn't mean it's not a closure.

Comment: @Cilyan: That is still a closure. The function `outer` closes over `inner`, no matter where you call it.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I was fooled by the code calling MAKE_FUNCTION instead of MAKE_CLOSURE: http://www.pastebin.ca/2535506

Answer (score 8):

Python supports nested scopes, by looking at how variables are used at compile time. Variables that you assign to in a function (or bind to with an `import` in a function) are considered local, everything else is non-local. Trying to delete a variable also marks it as a local.

Non-local names are searched for in parent scopes, and if not found are considered global.

In your second example, `x` refers to the name in the parent scope. You didn't assign to it, so it is a nested name, and can be seen in the local namespace. It is not *actually* a local name, but a free variable; it's value is taken from the parent scope instead.

In your last example, you try to delete `x`, making it a local name. Trying to reference it before anything was assigned to it results in an exception.

This is all documented in the [Execution model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html) documentation of the Python reference. Specifically:

> When a name is used in a code block, it is resolved using the nearest
>   enclosing scope. The set of all such scopes visible to a code block is
>   called the block’s *environment*.
>
> If a name is bound in a block, it is a local variable of that block.
>   If a name is bound at the module level, it is a global variable. (The
>   variables of the module code block are local and global.) If a
>   variable is used in a code block but not defined there, it is a *free
>   variable*.
>
> The following constructs bind names: formal parameters to functions,
>   `import` statements, class and function definitions (these bind the
>   class or function name in the defining block), and targets that are
>   identifiers if occurring in an assignment, `for` loop header, in the
>   second position of an `except` clause header or after `as` in a with
>   statement. The `import` statement of the form `from ... import *` binds
>   all names defined in the imported module, except those beginning with
>   an underscore. This form may only be used at the module level.
>
> A target occurring in a `del` statement is also considered bound for
>   this purpose (though the actual semantics are to unbind the name). It
>   is illegal to unbind a name that is referenced by an enclosing scope;
>   the compiler will report a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 0):

there is an explanation [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value) on the python docs faq page, similar to the above answers by abarnert and Martijn.

Comment: thanks for the post but its bit different from what I was looking, because there is not local assignment in my snippet.